# Sketch Probability density function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

My question is :

Suppose that the PDF of a random variable X is as follows:
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
       ce^{-2x} & \text {$x > 0$}\\
       0    & \text {otherwise}\\
       \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
    (a) Find the value of the constant c and sketch the PDF.

I am able to calculate value of c = 2. But when I try to plot PDF on mathematica using below code, it throws me below error.

```
{xlow, xhigh} = {0, Infinity}; 
Clear[pdf, x, t]; 
pdf[x_] := 2 e^(-2x)
pdfplot = Plot[pdf[x], {x, xlow, xhigh}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Purple}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "pdf[x]"}, AspectRatio - > 1/GoldenRatio]
```

Error:

```
Plot::plln: Limiting value Infinity in {x, xlow, xhigh} is not a machine-sized real number.   Plot::plln: Limiting value Infinity in {x, xlow, xhigh} is not a machine-sized real number.   Plot::plln:Limiting value Infinity in {x, xlow, xhigh} is not a machine-sized real number.
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Euler's number is written with a capital E in mathematica, or as esc-ee-esc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `E` rather than `e`

```
{xlow, xhigh} = {0, Infinity};
Clear[pdf, x, t];
pdf[x_] := 2 E^(-2 x)
```

You can use `xhigh` (i.e., `Infinity`) in a function like `Integrate`

```
Integrate[pdf[x], {x, xlow, xhigh}]
```

> 1

However, a `Plot` must be on a finite domain

```
Plot[pdf[x], {x, xlow, 6}, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Purple}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "pdf[x]"}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: My graph is not touching on Y axis with your code. How do you mention the X/Y axis steps in between the plotted points of 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 etc

Comment: See the documentation on `Ticks` to specify tick number, subdivisions, styling, and so on.